# Additional source and target folder with maven

Tags: java, maven, build

I have some test resources that need to be compiled and must not be in the same target folder as the tests themselfe. I was able to specify a separate directory for the test resources in the target directory. But then I figured out, that files in any resources folder are not compiled at all. Again, it is necessary to have the compiled test-resources in a separat directory then the tests and program source.

My project setup was something like this:

```
src
   | main
         |java
         |resources
   | test
         |java
         |resources (containing to be compiled test resources)
```

I came up with something like this:

```
src
   | main
         |java
         |resources
   | test
         |java
         |resources
   | testresources
         |java (containing to be compiled test resources)
         |resources
```

I already found out, how to use `build-helper-maven-plugin` to add additional source folders, but I wasn't able to also add additional target folders. Is there a way to do this?

What I want to have after running for example `mvn test` is:

```
target
     | classes
     | test-classes
     | testresources-classes
```

Where classes contains all compiled code from src/main, test-classes the compiled code from src/test and testresources-classes the compiled code from the src/testresources folder.

Comment: There's something odd here. Why do you need to _compile_ resources? Resources are simple files (like XML or properties), they are not source code.

Comment: I agree that these are not typical test resources. Maybe i'll rename that. My question still holds: Is there a way to put compiled srces into a specific target folder? I'm working on a static analysis that works on bytocode (.class files). The "resources" are actual java code that I need to have compiled for the tests.

Comment: The compiled classes from `src/testresources/java` will be located in `target/classes` (or `target/test-classes` depending if you added the directory as source or test-source). I'm not sure it is possible to specify a different directory.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I found out how to accomplish that, but I definitely want to place the compiled classes in a separat directory.

Comment: Look this  => http://www.agile-engineering.net/2011/06/seperating-maven-unit-integration-tests.html

Comment: Have you tried it? I tried it with the phases and folders of my need and it didn't work. Also I tried the original code snipped, but after running "mvn clean integration-test" there is no integrationtest-classes directory under target. Maven also doesn't give me any output about things that may went wrong.